# HTML to PPT Conversion .Net Library

Tags: html, css, .net, export, powerpoint

I am built a web based reporting engine that produces html/css based reports.  I am using Essential Objects HTMLtoPDF library for pdf exporting and EPPLus for excel exporting.  However, we are struggling to find a .NET library that can convert html into Powerpoint format.  Are there any tools out there that might work?

Answer (score 0):

You can create your customize wrapper around it for more usability.

https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/How-to-Create-PowerPoint-f285416a

Comment: Thanks but is there a way to convert my already produced html into ppt using Spire?